# How to make sure if the both source and target tables have same number of records after modification? How to sync?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am copying data from one database to another having similar tables using `Insert....select`.

Now, it's ok but if the source db has edited something and I want it to be updated in the target database table then that would be a problem.

I have few solutions:

1. If record exists (would verify using a GUID we have) then
   Delete it and its child data and Insert all again hence new updated data.
2. Taking union of the tables

   ```
   SELECT * FROM SourceDb.dbo.Table1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM TargetDb.dbo.Table2
   ```

If you get records greater than any of two tables, they don't have same data and needs to be deleted and re-add.

But problem is I have around 1 parent and around 7 child table so taking and checking using union would take me some extra coding.

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general query to verify that set A = set B is :

```
A - B U B - A = ∅ (set theory)
```

You can use the above query :

```
WITH
TA AS (SELECT * FROM databaseA.SchemaA.TableA),
TB AS (SELECT * FROM databaseB.SchemaB.TableB)
SELECT * FROM TA
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TB
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TB
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TA;
```

Comment: The double-except is so awesome and useful. I find `except` generally underappreciated.